# Changing Users Access by Ip Address in Login System on PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address, registration

Good day guys,

this should be the most difficult system that I will implement. So please help me regarding this system. Here is the flow of the system:

The user will login to the website using his/her computer in the office. But what if he/she wants to access it outside the office? When the user wants to access the website outside the company, the system will not permitted to access the user to the website. but it will prompt him/her a dialog box box says "Please contact MIS (075) 653-3106). Now once the user call the MIS, the admin of the website will accept the user request then the admin give a user registration page to the user to create a new user access.

When the user registered his/her user account, the admin will verify the user and the user can access the website outside the company. When the user want to access the website (this time the user is in the office) he/she will do again on what i've said (please contact mis, verify, user registration).

The problem is that to successfully implement this, the system will verify an ip address of the computer that the user will use to access the site. Once the user access the website, the computer that he/she will use is must match the registered ip address on the system to the ip address of the computer that he/she is using. When the user wants to access outside the company. The admin will give a user registration page but it will register a new ip address of the computer and it will change the ip_address value together with the username and password value on the mysql database so that the user access and the new ip address will be registered on the system so that the user can access the website outside the company. Same goes if the user will use his/her computer on the office.

I am using php and mysql database so can you please help me with these. It is a very complicated system so i really need help on how to do this.

Thanks guys

Comment: Creating an additional table with the userid and the allowed ips and loop through them to see if they match on the login?

Comment: username and password for secure login system for the website. But they can access the site anywhere and anytime. I want to configure the system that will only identify the ip address of the computer that the user is using. So that the user cannot access it outside the company because of the registered ip address on the database.

Comment: To that, I reply, "Make it so".

Answer (score 0):

Here's the flow:

- User visits the index.php page. The system finds the IP address and checks the database to see if they are already known. If it doesn't find it, it is inserted into a "temporary" database that marks the IP address and "not activated."
- The user calls your number and the person checks the database (maybe with a GUI) and sees that the user accessed the site with a wrong IP address. He marks the IP address as allowed, and then the user reloads his page and is given a registration form to make a new user account with, and the IP address gets associated with the user account.
- If the user has multiple endpoints, they are added into the ip_address table which has the following structure:

  +----+---------+------------+-----------+
  | id | user_id | ip_address | activated |
  +----+---------+------------+-----------+

That way, user_id's can be associated with multiple IP addresses, but they might not be activated. If a user visits without an account on a non-allowed IP address, they're added with a NULL user_id (because they don't have an account, yet) and a 0 for 'activated' because they have not been allowed into the system. When the administrator marks them as allowed, he puts a 1 for activated and the user registers. then they register, the user_id is placed in the user_id column.

Hope that makes sense,

David

Comment: What you described is extremely involved and would take some time. I can tell you, however, that `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` is how you get PHP to get the IP address. I'd gladly do it if you would be interested in paying me... this is a lot of work.